# What WCF binding to use to communicate between two processes with different privileges on the same machine?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, named-pipes, nettcpbinding

I have two processes on the same machine that need to communicate via WCF. One process is the main business application that will be running with very low privileges on the system. The other process is a "watchdog" that will be monitoring the main application and this process should be running as a Windows Service and have a lot more privileges (eg. maybe even running as Admin).

These two processes need to communicate via WCF and with good performance. The idea is that both processes implement a WCF service and processes will use to communicate with each other. Eg. main application will provide health monitoring service while watchdog process will provide service that main app will use to execute tasks that require higher privileges. (I am also considering duplex WCF channel communication but it seems to me that two separate WCF services are more cleaner approach right now.)

The watchdog process should "ping" the main application in configurable interval (eg. once in a 0.1 to 10 seconds). Thus I thought to use **named pipes** as the WCF transport but I have concerns if this kind of inter-process communication will be possible given that two processes have different privileges. So are there any issues if named pipes are used in this scenario with WCF communication between two processes of different privileges? Would using TCP bindings instead avoid this type of issues?

Comment: what you have tried  so  far  otherway it's a primary opinion  based  question

Answer (score 0):

Use [nterprocess Communication](http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication)

If they are on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

Probably NetNamedPipeBinding. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).